# svn log command with--depth option

Tags: svn

I need to get the log for specific directory in SVN database non-recursively.

```
   svn.exe log HTTP://10.0.3.2:8080/svn/New/Projects --depth 'empty'
```

It shows,

```
svn: E205000: ''empty'' is not a valid depth; try 'empty', 'files', 'immediates', or 'infinity'
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: try to remove quotation: `svn.exe log HTTP://10.0.3.2:8080/svn/New/Projects --depth empty`

Comment: Same error if i remove quotes also

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine, why you want this strange command, but

`''empty'' is not a valid depth`

tells me, that your client OS is Windows, in this case you have to write "empty"

And --depth doesn't work without --diff, thus you final command must be

`svn.exe log HTTP://10.0.3.2:8080/svn/New/Projects --depth "empty" --diff`

(log for `/New/Projects` only, without childs, *without file-lists* in log, but *with property-changes*, if they happened)

PS: for  --depth "empty" I can't detect expected useful effect of ignoring childs:

`svn log URL/branches/ --depth "empty" --diff`

show **all** revisions, which happened in all branches

Comment: I need logs for /New/Projects only, not all...                               svn.exe log HTTP://10.0.3.2:8080/svn/New/Projects --depth "empty" --diff                    it shows all logs. i dont want that

Comment: @user1553605 - btw, you can't get it with pure log. read `svn help log`: " The --depth option is only valid in combination with the --diff option
  and **limits the scope of the displayed diff** to the specified depth."

Comment: I don't know why the OP wants this, but I'm desperately looking for some way to identify which commits were the results of a merge. Looking for changes on the directory itself (i.e., it's properties) seems like a good start for filtering down.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the quotes **'** around the `empty` keyword and with a `=` sign.

```
svn.exe log http://10.0.3.2:8080/svn/New/Projects --depth=empty
```

Comment: if i give without quotes, it shows: svn: E205000: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205000: 'depth' option requires 'diff' option

Comment: @user1553605 : try to add an equal sign : `--depth=empty`

Answer (score 0):

You need an other tool eg. *grep* to filter out the log lines which are not relevant to you

```
svn log http://10.0.3.2:8080/svn/New/Projects --depth empty --diff | grep +++ -B 7 -A 6
```

this shows the 7 lines before and the 6 lines after a property change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue ... I suspect that the problem is likely due to the inter-operability between the client and server.

My client version:

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)
   compiled Apr 14 2013, 10:11:47
```

My server:

```
Subversion 1.6.2 (r37639)
```

It looks like the --depth option isn't available in version 1.6.x of the client

1.7.9 client:

```
$ svn log --help | grep depth
  The --depth option is only valid in combination with the --diff option
  and limits the scope of the displayed diff to the specified depth.
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
$
```

1.6.x client:

```
$ svn log --help | grep depth
Previous exit value was: 1
$
```